# Marklogic Dls versioning Issue

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I have inserted the XML document into Marklogic DB using **dls:document-insert-and-manage** function  after that I have modified the XML document using **dls:document-checkout-update-checkin** function, now we have 2 versions available in the ML. But in the 1st version we have only name available and the content got erased.Can you please correct me if anything wrong on my side, especially on configuration ?

```
Versions
/15/a679_xml_versions/1-a679.xml
/15/a679_xml_versions/2-a679.xml
```

I have use this query

```
doc("/15/a679_xml_versions/1-a679.xml")
```

but the result was

```
"your query returned an empty sequence"
```

Comment: I have used the dls:retention-rule-insert function this function is working fine I am able to see the old version content , But I have another issue I have updated the same content again and again using dls:document-checkout-update-checkin function but version get increased . My question is if the content is same then how to increase version ? Can you please suggest anything missing from my side?

Answer (score 3):

Do you have any retention policies defined? Old versions of documents are kept if they match some retention policy. You can define polices that match documents based on their age, contents, collections, etc.

Here are a couple links, in case you haven't seen them yet.

http://docs.marklogic.com/dls/retention
http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/dls

Wayne.

Comment: I have created the dls:retention-rule for all documents but it's not working as excepted.   http://docs.marklogic.com/dls:retention-rule

Comment: I have used the dls:retention-rule-insert function this function is working fine I am  able to see the old version content , But I have another issue I have updated the same content again and again  using dls:document-checkout-update-checkin function but version get increased . My question is if the content is same then how to increase version ? Can you please suggest anything missing from my side?

Comment: The library doesn't check whether you've made changes. It assumes that since you're calling checkout-update-checkin() that you have actually made a change.